# Trying to grab just absolute links from a webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am reading the contents of a webpage using BeautifulSoup. What I want is to just grab the `<a href>` that start with `http://`. I know in beautifulsoup you can search by the attributes. I guess I am just having a syntax issue. I would imagine it would go something like.

```
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.linkpages.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if link['href'].startswith('http://'):
        print links
```

But that returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\BeautifulSoup.py", line 598, in __getitem__
    return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*
This isn't for any site in particular. The script gets the url from the user. So internal link targets would be an issue, that's also why I only want the `<'a'>` from the pages. If I turn it towards `www.reddit.com`, it parses the beginning links and it gets to this:

```
<a href="http://www.reddit.com/top/">top</a>
<a href="http://www.reddit.com/saved/">saved</a>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\BeautifulSoup.py", line 598, in __getitem__
    return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

Comment: reddit.com has this: <a class="pretty-button negative"></a>. So, it's not a syntax error, it is API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.linkpages.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
    print link
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you possibly have some `<a>` tags without `href` attributes?  Internal link targets, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Please give us an idea of what you're parsing here - as Andrew points out, it seems likely that there are some anchor tags without associated hrefs.

If you really want to ignore them, you could wrap it in a try block and afterwards catch with

`except KeyError:
    pass`

But that has its own issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open('Links.txt','w')
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='http://www.redit.com'
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page)
atags=soup.find_all('a')
for item in atags:
    for x in item.attrs: 
        if x=='href':
            f.write(item.attrs[x]+',\n')
        else:
            continue
f.close()
```

A less efficient solution.